# Pegar um valor de vários arrays dentro de um array

Tags: php, array

Tenho uma duvida em relação a um array, tenho um array que guarda vários arrays dentro, esse é o resultado:

```
Array (
   [0] => Array ( 
       [membro_id] => 1465 
       [membro_nome] => Gustavo Silva de Oliveira 
       [membro_estado] => 4 
       [membro_cidade] => Humaití 
       [membro_status] => 1 
       [membro_validade] => 31/07/2018 
       [estado_id] => 4 
       [estado_codigouf] => 13 
       [estado_nome] => Amazonas
       [estado_uf] => AM
       [estado_regiao] => 1 
       [status_id] => 1
       [status_nome] => Ativo
   )
   [1] => Array (
       [membro_id] => 1581 
       [membro_nome] => Ânio Neves de Souza
       [membro_estado] => 4 
       [membro_cidade] => Manaus
       [membro_status] => 1
       [membro_validade] => 31/07/2019
       [estado_id] => 4
       [estado_codigouf] => 13
       [estado_nome] => Amazonas
       [estado_uf] => AM
       [estado_regiao] => 1
       [status_id] => 1
       [status_nome] => Ativo
   )
)
```

Quero pegar o campo  `[membro_status] => 1` de cada resultado, fiz o seguinte `$membros[0]['membro_status']`, porém só retorna o primeiro `array`, alguém poderia dar um help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Victor, tudo bem?
Use a função foreach do php.

```
foreach($nome_da_variavel as $nome_individual){
    var_dump($nome_individual);
}
```

Segue link do Manual PHP.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Caso tenha dificuldade na confecção do código só pedir.

Comment: Na mosca man, obrigado!

Comment: Por favor, informe que a sua pergunta foi respondida.

Comment: @VictorHugo coloque a resposta como certa. Fica abaixo da do lugar da pontuação. Só você tem esse poder.

Answer (score 1):

Use o foreach

```
foreach($arrays as $array) {
  $status = $array["membro_status"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simples.

```
$novoArray = array_column($seuArray,'membro_id');
print_r($novoArray);
```

Pode ser interessante usando o terceiro parâmetro em que o array é retornado com a chave=>valor. Exemplo:

```
$novoArray = array_column($seuArray,'membro_status', 'membro_nome');
print_r($novoArray);
```

Onde chave é a coluna informada como terceiro parâmetro e value o segundo parâmetro.